# resizing a picture so that it will show up on a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a UITabBarController and I want to add a picture of a house onto my first tab which is labeled "Home". I found some pictures on google images of houses but when I tried to resize it to 30 by 30 pixels using pixlr the end result was all messed up and it was hard to understand. I tried inserting this into xcode but the square for the picture is just a gray square because xcode doesn't allow the picture quality that I had. Is there any way to easily resize a picture and make it legible so that xcode will accept it?

Comment: How about adobe photoshop?

Comment: I looked at p hotoshop, but apparently it costs money I'm looking fr=or something that is free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Just double click the image ,it will go to the default picture app published by app ,then there will be a tools option open it.

1. click Adjust Size.

2.[image]

you can edit the what pixel size you want thanks :) ......